# How do I include a Javascript Library from a Twig Extension in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a custom Twig Extension that needs to add a Javascript library **ONLY** when the Twig Extension is used.

Here is my `modules/custom/MY_MODULE/MY_MODULE.libraries.yml`:

```
my-twig-extension:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/myTwigExtension.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Here is my `modules/custom/MY_MODULE/js/myTwigExtension.js` (just for testing):

```
console.log("Hello World!!! at " + Date.now());
```

In my `modules/custom/MY_MODULE/src/TwigExtension.php` I define the extension here:

```
public function getFunctions() {
    return [
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('MY_MODULE_widget', [$this, 'MY_MODULEWidget']),
    ];
}
```

and then it's function:

```
public function MY_MODULEWidget($MY_VARIABLE)
{
    return array(
            '#theme' => 'twig_extension_MY_MODULE_widget',
            '#MY_VARIABLE' => $MY_VARIABLE,
            );
}
```

The `#theme` above is correctly loading my file here `modules/custom/MY_MODULE/templates/twig_extension_MY_MODULE_widget.html.twig`:

```html
<div class="MY_CLASS" data-MY_VARIABLE="{{ MY_VARIABLE | url_encode }}">Loading Widget...</div>
```

#### Attempt 0:

Added the following twig function to `modules/custom/MY_MODULE/templates/twig_extension_MY_MODULE_widget.html.twig`:

```
{{ attach_library('MY_MODULE/my-twig-extension') }}
```

but that did not work.

#### Attempt 1:

Tried adding the library in the render array:

```php
public function MY_MODULEWidget($MY_VARIABLE)
{
    return array(
            '#theme' => 'twig_extension_MY_MODULE_widget',
            '#MY_VARIABLE' => $MY_VARIABLE,
            '#attached' => array(
                'library' => array(
                    'MY_MODULE/my-twig-extension',
                    ),
                ),
            );
}
```

but it doesn't look like `BlockBase` logic is supported here to load the library.

#### Attempt 2:

I looked at how the Twig function `attach_library` works and saw how in `Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension::attachLibrary($library)` worked and tried to implement it here like this:

```php
public function MY_MODULEWidget($job_name)
{
    static $doOnce = true;
    if ($doOnce) {
        $doOnce = false;

        /* @var $renderer Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer */
        $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
        $template_attached = ['#attached' => ['library' => ['MY_MODULE/my-twig-extension']]];
        $renderer->render($template_attached);
    }

    return array(
            '#theme' => 'twig_extension_adicio_rated_job_widget',
            '#job_name' => $job_name,
            );
}
```

... with the idea of including the library the first time the Twig Extension was called.  But no go.

**IMPORTANT:** yeah I know I can add the following to my `module/custom/MY_MODULE/MY_MODULE.info.yml`:

```
libraries:
  - MY_MODULE/my-twig-extension
```

but I do not want to load this library (very expensive logic), to every page.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Someone with 300+ reputation, please add the `twig-extension` Tag to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial Answer that works**

... but I don't like it because the list of paths in the config never gets reset.  I think I need to figure out how to do *Cache Contexts* for a proper answer.

In my `modules/custom/MY_MODULE/src/TwigExtension.php` file:

```php
class TwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension 
{
   const CONFIG_KEY_NAME = 'MY_CONFIG_NAME';
...
    public function MY_MODULEWidget($MY_VARIABLE)
    {
        /* @var $config Drupal\Core\Config\Config */
        $config = $this->configFactory->getEditable($this->getName() . '.settings');

        $paths = (array)$config->get(self::CONFIG_KEY_NAME);

        /* @var $currentPath string */
        $currentPath = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();        // returns '/node/47446' not the alias

        if (in_array($currentPath, $paths)) {
            // Good
        } else {
            // Add $currentPath to config
            $paths[] = $currentPath;
            $config->set(self::CONFIG_KEY_NAME, $paths)->save();
        }

        return array(
                '#type' => 'inline_template',
                '#template' => '<div class="MY_CLASS" data-MY_DATA="{{ MY_VARIABLE }}">Loading Widget ...</div>',
                '#context' => array(
                    'MY_VARIABLE' => $MY_VARIABLE,
                    ),
                );
    }
}
```

The above code will add the current path to a config.  Unknown if there's an upper limit to the size of the data in the config; however, in my implementation the number of pages that this is on will be small (< 100).

Then once the path is added to the module's config setting then we read it to conditionally add a library like this using `hook_page_bottom()` like this in my `modules/custom/MY_MODULE/MY_MODULE.module` file:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_page_bottom
 */
function MY_MODULE_page_bottom(array &$page_bottom)
{
    /* @var $paths array of strings */
    $paths = (array)\Drupal::config('MY_MODULE.settings')->get(Drupal\MY_MODULE\TwigExtension::CONFIG_KEY_NAME);

    /* @var $currentPath string */
    $currentPath = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();     // like '/node/47446', not the Alias

    if (in_array($currentPath, $paths)) {
        // Include the library that will modify jQuery(".MY_CLASS")
       $page_bottom['MY_MODULE']['#attached']['library'][] = 'MY_MODULE/my-twig-extension';
    }     

}
```

**EDIT 0**

Added a `hook_build()` to my module like this so I could clear the setting manually:

```php
function MY_MODULE_rebuild()
{
    /* @var $config Drupal\Core\Config\Config */
    $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('MY_MODULE.settings');

    $config->clear(Drupal\MY_MODULE\TwigExtension::CONFIG_KEY_NAME);

    $config->save();

}
```

Note: $config support fluid interface (e.g. $config->clear(...).

I will still not accept my answer because I still believe I should be using *Cache Context* for this.

Comment: I will not accept my answer because the above solution doesn't get cleared when the widget no longer exists on a page (in my case a View).  Oh, also notice I used an `inline_template` instead of creating another `.html.twig` file.  The template used is actually much more complex that what I showed.  Technically don't need to add a '#context', I know.

Comment: EDIT 0 - added hook_build()

Comment: I feel bad accepting my own answer but this is what I went with to production.  Its works.